# How can I close all ports in windows firewall when they are set to be open by a domain policy?

Tags: windows, firewall

All I get in windows firewall is:

"For your security some setitngs are managed by your network administrator"

(I'm local admin)

Comment: Well, you could unplug your computer physically from the network...  Does the same thing ;p

Answer (score 1):

Just speak to whoever manages your group policies - why work around them when they're probably just a phone call and 5 minute chat away that will leave you with a fully supported solution rather than one you need to manage yourself.

Comment: And working around the policies may get you more trouble that it's worth. It's a firing offence in many companies.

Comment: Us techies get so tied up in fixing problems using technical means that we forget that many of these issues are *better* resolved by questioning requirements, negotiation and people/process changes.

Comment: Ah but the reason for this is that we tend play quite a lot of pranks on each other in our office. So I'd like to disable remote access to my PC. I won't get in any trouble.

Comment: @user1165189 - please read our FAQ, this site is for professional sysadmins, not prankster - please use the site accordingly.

Comment: Yes but if you read my comment you will see that they are the pranksters not I